# How to add vertical line to a plot which has a xlab in time format

Tags: r, time, ggplot2

Considering a plot provided with the following code:

```
x<-seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:05:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 00:00:00"), by = '5 min')
t<-as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 07:08:32")
y<-c(1:288)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
library('ggplot2')
p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
p
```

Now I want to add a vertical line which locates at `2016-01-01 07:08:32`, so I tried the following:

```
p+geom_vline(xintercept=as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 07:08:32"))
```

However, this is not the solution and it returns:

```
Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

How could I get the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap the date in `as.numeric`

```
p+geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")))
```